# I'm having some problems with my notebook's touchpad

Tags: drivers, xorg, touchpad, synaptics, xserver

I'm having some problems with my notebook's touchpad. This event appeared after I typed the command `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. The problem is that when I scroll up it goes down, when I scroll down it goes up, and the side does not work at all.

It didn't work when I tried using these commands.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
syncclient TouchpadOff=0
syncclient TouchpadOff=1
sudo service lightdm restart
sudo systemctl restart graphical.target
```

Comment: read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. No mention is made of the distro/version you are using for starters...

Comment: FYI:  I personally find I get better if I match the chosen kernel stack with the hardware; especially using the newest stack available for my release when using newish hardware, but also using the older stack if using older hardware. You didn't provide any OS/release details; are you using the best stack for your *unstated* product/release?  You didn't give us that basic detail; so consider what you installed (*defaults are set by install media with Ubuntu*) in relation to your *unstated* hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like natural scrolling is turned on.

Download Dconf Editor from Software center. Open it, in the search bar type "natural-scroll". Turn the value to "False" and apply.